# Scanner and nextInt discard integer

Tags: java, input

I am using Scanner for taking user input in java. when i use nextInt() and the user inputs "2 5", then the value "2" is assigned and 5 is thrown away. What if I want to display that such an input is an error?
One solution that comes to my mind is that i can use nextString() instead of nextInt() and then work my way out. But can anybody suggest a better solution?

i realized that it is not throwing away the integer after space, instead it is using it for the next input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test{
static Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
static void trial(){
    int k=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(k);
}

public static void main(String[] args){     
    int k=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(k);
    trial();        
}
}
```

Comment: `nextInt()` will read one `int`. If you want to read the other one, call it again.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you please post the code snippet as well? Did you try calling nextInt() again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** First use `nextLine()` to **read the entire line.**

**2.** Use `Integer.parseInt()` method to **validate the integer input**.

**Eg:**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.nextLine();

try{
    Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Its not a valid Integer");
}
```

Comment: But if have two integers typed with a space as a delimiter, parseInt will always fail. We need split the string that we get from nextLine(). i.e we should go for parsing only after we split the string, otherwise it will always throw an error "Its not a valid integer" for above mentioned case.

Comment: I have given the answer according to the question, that is how to validate a single or a pair of digit separated by a space. Consider 15 is a an integer, writing "1 5" using split with space as delimiter will consider 1 and 5 as two digits, but the user doesnt want it that way.....

Comment: As a small suggestion: Use Apache Commons StringUtils.isNumeric(String); This will tell you, if the String is infact a valid number. IMHO using Exceptions this way is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd suggest reading the line all-at-once, and using String.split() to parse the individual "words":

> http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html
>
> We want to divide up a phrase into words where spaces are used to
>   separate words. For example

```
the music made   it   hard      to        concentrate
```

> In this case, we have just one delimiter (space) and consecutive
>   delimiters (i.e., several spaces in a row) should be treated as one
>   delimiter. To parse this string in Java, we do

```
String phrase = 
  "the music made   it   hard      to        concentrate"; 
String delims = "[ ]+"; 
String[] tokens =  phrase.split(delims);
```

Comment: I would not recommend String.split() to any Java newbie. You are directly sending him into his next batch of problems somewhere in the future, caused by the fact that the split argument is a regular expression, which he will have forgotten again after short time.

Comment: Regular expressions are hugely powerful: better to find them sooner than later. Plus, newbie programs are easier to debug - if your first regular expression mistake comes in a 5000 line program, you are much more stuck.

Comment: loosely related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems

Answer (score 0):

Use `readLine()` from [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). You will get a `String` containing everything that the user types up to Enter. From there, you can do what you want with the input and check that it conforms to your expected formatting.