# Methods' outputting twice with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have to basically make a program that would add a name given a prompt and place it in the array. It should do the same for the age of the person. I have been forced to do this with methods. The only issue i am having is that with the 3rd last line, the name get's asked twice. I don't know how to fix that. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Testing1 {
public static int[] ageinput(String names[], int q2){
    int holderage[] = new int[q2];
    for(int x = 0; x<q2;x++) {``
        System.out.println("Please input the age of " + names[x]);
        Scanner age = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a1 = age.nextInt();
        holderage[x] = a1;
    }
    return holderage;
}
public static String[] nameinput(int q2){
    String holdername[] = new String[q2];
    for (int x = 0; x<q2;x++) {
        System.out.println("Please input the name of the person");
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n1 = name.nextLine();
        holdername[x]=n1;
    }
    return holdername;

}
public static void output(String names[], int ages[]){
    for(int x = 0; x<names.length;x++){
        System.out.println(names[x]+" is "+ages[x]+" years old");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many names do you want to input?");
    Scanner question = new Scanner(System.in);
    int q1 = question.nextInt();
    output(nameinput(q1),ageinput(nameinput(q1),q1));
}
```

}

Comment: Please do your homework yourself.

Comment: Have you considered problems with `nextInt`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643222/scanner-and-nextint-discard-integer)?

Comment: Yes, but it is just that it is so close. The only problem is that it outputs twice and i know that it is because of output(nameinput(q1),ageinput(nameinput(q1),q1));, but i don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what exactly is going on. The answer is simple, and we are not here to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

In `output(nameinput(q1),ageinput(nameinput(q1),q1));` you call the method `nameinput` twice, so the code also will be executed twice.
You could ask the names in `nameinput`, store them into an array and pass that array to `ageinput`.

Comment: Ok i fixed it. Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience if any Dakkaron.

Answer (score 0):

@Aadithya Gowthaman, try this one in your editor.

```
package com.aamir;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing1 {
public static int[] ageinput(String names[], int q2){
int holderage[] = new int[q2];
for(int x = 0; x<q2;x++) {
    System.out.println("Please input the age of " + names[x]);
    Scanner age = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a1 = age.nextInt();
    holderage[x] = a1;
}
return holderage;
}
public static String[] nameinput(int q2){
    String holdername[] = new String[q2];
    for (int x = 0; x<q2;x++) {
    System.out.println("Please input the name of the person");
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n1 = name.nextLine();
    holdername[x]=n1;
}
return holdername;

}
public static void output(String names[], int ages[]){
for(int x = 0; x<names.length;x++){
    System.out.println(names[x]+" is "+ages[x]+" years old");
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("How many names do you want to input?");
Scanner question = new Scanner(System.in);
int q1 = question.nextInt();
String [] namesArray =  nameinput(q1);
int [] ageArray =  ageinput(namesArray, q1);

output(namesArray, ageArray);
}
}
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.